# Android Application crash, ListActivity Class, issue with inflator for customized view each row

Tags: android

My `MainActivity` is extended with `ListActivity` and in the `onCreate` method I've following code

```
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    R.id.textView1,
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries)));
```

And this class with in my MainActivity scope

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, true);

        TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

        tv.setText(items[position]);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_1);


        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

}
```

Now when I run this code the app crashes with the alert error

> Unfortunately, APPLICATION_NAME has stopped

I think something is wrong with this line `View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, true);`

**PS:** I'm very new to the Android and have no idea why this is happening, `LogCat` is too ugly to read, but here's the few lines:

```
10-19 13:06:09.878: D/AndroidRuntime(1736): Shutting down VM
10-19 13:06:09.878: W/dalvikvm(1736): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:477)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at com.me.listexample.MainActivity$MyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:57)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
10-19 13:06:09.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:494)
```

Comment: Change to `return row`and remove  `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)`

Comment: check my post and try the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Constructor

```
 LayoutInflater inflator;
 String items[];
 public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        String[] strings) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    inflator = LayoutInflate.from(context);
    this.items = strings;
}
```

In `getView`

```
View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
ImageView iv = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
tv.setText(items[position]);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_1);
return view;
```

Remove

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
```

You are already passing the array to the costructor of adapter class

Also it is better you use a `ViewHolder` pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Edit:

```
static class ViewHolder
{
TextView tv;
ImageView iv;
}
```

In getView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.iv= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        holder.tv.setText(items[position]);
        holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_1);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about `Also it is better you use a ViewHolder pattern` but i will definitely take a look at your link

Comment: Also I have one question what is the difference between the way I have defined `inflator` and yours

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This,

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

            TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            String[] items = (Activity)context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

            tv.setText(items[position]);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_1);


            return row;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

Write

```
View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
```

instead of

```
View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, true);
```